# Create a test environment database in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to build a ruby gem that uses active_record to connect to a database. How can I configure a separate test and regular database (like rails) so that the test database is used while running tests and the regular database is used otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using PostgreSQL, you would set it in your `database.yml` file:

```
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_test
  pool: 5
  username: username
  password:
```

You haven't explained what you mean by "regular database", but it could be `development` or `production`.

Then you have a second entry in the `database.yml` file for it.

Comment: That would be in a rails app. I am working on a gem created through `bundle gem gem_name`.

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be a Rails app. It will work for any app with ActiveRecord.

Comment: Thanks, so this will involve manual parsing of the yaml file and setting the database explicity before the tests?

Comment: You should be able to use the activerecord gem, then call ``ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config[ENV['RACK_ENV']])`` (assuming environment variable ``RACK_ENV`` is set to test)

Comment: Yes. https://gist.github.com/georgeu2000/034a8de58402ac33436aa1c967f4eac7

Comment: I'm not using rack either. But I guess I can use a custom environment variable that I can set to `test` before running the tests.

Comment: Yes, `RACK_ENV` is just a convention. You can use `RUBY_ENV` or something else.